# schroedinger tuple, is a tuple and not a tuple

Tags: python, opencv

I have a tuple of tuples built using individual numerical values

```
 maxcontour = ( (minx,miny),(maxx,miny),(maxx,maxy),(minx,maxy) )
```

and is indeed a tuple

```
 print (maxcontour)
```

> ((374, 0), (2553, 0), (2553, 3999), (374, 3999))

but when using it where a tuple is expected

```
  cv2.polylines(img, maxcontour, True, (0,0,255), 5 )
```

I get this error

> error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'polylines'
> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - pts is not a numerical tuple
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'pts'

I am obviously overlooking something very basic, but I can't see what; and the error message *"Expected Ptrcv::UMat for argument 'pts'"* is of no great help.

What is the way to create a "numerical tuple" valid for `cv.polylines()`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html#drawing-polygon) it seems like they expect you to use an [numpy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)?

Comment: It would seem the function expects a tuple of numbers, not a tuple of tuples of numbers

Comment: That is, indeed, a terrible error message. The C++ type should be "translated" into a Python type.

Comment: This is mostly due to the fact that the Python bindings are autogenerated. The first error is simply because the bindings only accept Python [tuples of integers or floats](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L689) (that's what the "numerical tuple" means). The second error due to the fact that for (most) functions there are two overloads generated -- one for regular arrays (which map to `cv::Mat`), second one for `UMat`. When resolving the overload, it fist tries the one for `Mat`, and if that fails to match arguments, then tries the `UMat` one.

Comment: looking at the example in doc, it look like the shape of the tuple should be `(((374, 0),), ((2553, 0),), ((2553, 3999),), ((374, 3999),))`, and give it inside a list... assuming of course it can take regular tuples

Comment: why is anyone here messing around with tuples? the API takes a list of numpy arrays (vector of cv::Mat). and why did @NathanielFord link to some random third-party outdated RTD site that isn't https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaa3c25f9fb764b6bef791bf034f6e26f5

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm sure you didn't mean your tone to come off as condescending, but it does. The linked site I used included a real example of usage, unlike the opencv.org API doc.

Comment: you are right. I'm sorry for my tone. however, that article is not "the docs" and its content actually does exist in OpenCV's own docs: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

Comment: AFAIK, the input to `polylines` is the same as the input to `drawContours`, which is the same thing as what `findContours` returns. So, inspect the output of `findContours` and generate something that looks like it. | It ought to be an array of polylines, where each polyline is defined as array of points, each point being an array of coordinate components.

Comment: thank for all of your thoughtful and useful comments. At least I feel relieved that more or less agree that the opencv docs are a mess and the error messages are painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nathaniel Ford said the points needs to be a numpy array

> To draw a polygon, first you need coordinates of vertices. Make those
> points into an array of shape ROWSx1x2 where ROWS are number of
> vertices and it should be of type int32.

So

```
maxcontour = np.array( [[minx,miny],[maxx,miny],[maxx,maxy],[minx,maxy]],np.int32)
maxcontour = maxcontour.reshape((-1,1,2))
cv2.polylines(img, [maxcontour], True, (0,0,255))
```